# LINQ Performance with SelectMany, GroupBy and First

Tags: c#, linq

Today I tried to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=5 with LINQ.

this works fine and executes in under 2sec on my machine, but is a little verbose:

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000)
    .Where(i => i % 2 == 0
        && i % 3 == 0
        && i % 4 == 0
        && i % 5 == 0
        && i % 6 == 0
        && i % 7 == 0
        && i % 8 == 0
        && i % 9 == 0
        && i % 10 == 0
        && i % 11 == 0
        && i % 12 == 0
        && i % 13 == 0
        && i % 14 == 0
        && i % 15 == 0
        && i % 16 == 0
        && i % 17 == 0
        && i % 18 == 0
        && i % 19 == 0
        && i % 20 == 0
    )
    .First()
```

so I tried to put the 2-19 range into a Enumerable too and do a crossjoin like so

```cs
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000)
    .SelectMany(n =>
        Enumerable.Range(2, 19)
            .Select(d => (n, d))
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.n)
    .Where(g => g.All(y => y.n % y.d == 0))
    .First()
    .Key
```

the issue with the second solution is that it allocates heavily, crashes in x86 LINQPad with an OutOfMemoryException, and eats up a whole lot of mem in the x64 LINQPad version before I kill it manually.

My question is why?
And is there a LINQ query that can avoid that issue?

The CLR Heap Allocation Analyzer plugin tells me that there is a heap allocation going on inside

```cs
.Select(d => (n, d))
```

due to the capturing of 'n'.
So I assume that is the reason for the OutOfMemoryException, but ...
since I use First() without materializing the query in between, I assumed that this should not be a problem, because linq would materialize the group and discard it again because it does not satisfy the condition while releasing the memory.
is there something funky going on with selectmany or groupby that forces all data to be materialized first, or is my mental model just wrong here?

Comment: wild guess - I cannot imagine generic `GroupBy` implementation without materialization of some sort

Comment: Are you asking why generating 1-18 elements for each single item in a Range of 1000000000 items throws an OutOfMemoryException? Kinda extremely easy to determine why

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is sure a valid comment if collection is materialized.. but actually question is _when_ it is materialized; you won't receive outofmemory for say `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000).First(x => x >=1000000000)`

Comment: For what it's worth, `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000).First(i => Enumerable.Range(2, 19).All(j => i % j == 0))` works fine.

Comment: @Lanorkin What makes you thinkg the collection *isn't* materialized? How do you think `g.All(y => y.n % y.d == 0)` is calculated?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto so just answer the question then :)

Comment: can the query be wrote such, that materialization is only done for one group at a time?

Comment: Why using LINQ? it's much easier with two nested for loops. for a better performance I suggest start checking if the number is even divisible starting from the higher number to the lower (from 20 to 2 instead of from 2 to 20) because if the given number is even divisible by 20 then it's already even divisible by some lower numbers (5, 4, 2)

Comment: why? a) to improve my linq skills and b) to bumb into issues like that, try to solve them, and learn even more.
going back to forth in the "inner loop" is a good optimization thx, will be incorporated.

Comment: @juharr you are right!! this works and is much easier. even though its 5 times slower than the first solution it does not explode :) if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Egi I just noticed that haim770 already posted that in an earlier comment.  The reason that works is that it's not creating 19000000000 items to group on.  It's looking at each value between 1 and 1000000000 and then looping through 2 to 20 to see if the number is divisible by all of them.  It's a bit slower because it has to generate those numbers for the check and them loop, versus your large logic operation which will execute much quicker.

Comment: @haim770 want to post an answer?

Comment: @Egi you can add `.Reverse()` to @haim770 code to achieve the optimization I mentioned earlier. `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000).First(i => Enumerable.Range(2, 19).Reverse().All(j => i % j == 0))`

Comment: Another reason why this fails is that it's a *brute force* method. If you add more denominators, at some point you'll end up with a `First()` that's beyond the max you try. The method isn't scalable. From an academic POV the question itself is interesting, but a viable solution should use an algorithm that [factorized the denominators first and then multiplies](http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/42865/Least-common-multiple).

Comment: You may wish to consider removing some of the superfluous `%` checks as well. `i % 20 == 0` for example, isn't needed (since `i % 2 == 0` already covers that)

Comment: only the numbers from 11 to 20 need to be checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried the following code, the same problem will occur:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000000)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .First();
```

This means that all groups will be materialized during execution of the query, and that's the reason why `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown.

To solve the problem, you can use the following LINQ code as mentioned by @haim770 in the comments section:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, 1000000000)
    .First(i => Enumerable
        .Range(2, 19)
        .All(j => i % j == 0))
```

For more optimization, I found a better solution. Sorry for not using LINQ but it's much more optimized, maybe there's a way to achieve it using LINQ.

Instead of looping through a large amount of numbers and check each one, why not building the desired answer directly.

The desired output is a number `x` that is divisible by all numbers `1..n` without any remainder. So, it is the multiple of all prime factors of numbers in range `1..n`. by taking minimal amount of these prime factors, we can get the smallest number `x`.

For example, if `n = 10` then:

```
i = 2: prime factors of 2 are [2] -> neededPrimes = [2]
i = 3: prime factors of 3 are [3] -> neededPrimes = [2, 3]
i = 4: prime factors of 4 are [2, 2] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 3] // we add just one 2 because the other already exists in neededPrimes
i = 5: prime factors of 5 are [5] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 3, 5]
i = 6: prime factors of 6 are [2, 3] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 3, 5] // we add nothing because [2, 3] are already in neededPrimes
i = 7: prime factors of 7 are [7] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 3, 5, 7]
i = 8: prime factors of 8 are [2, 2, 2] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7] // we add one 2 because the other 2's already exist in neededPrimes
i = 9: prime factors of 9 are [3, 3] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7]
i = 10: prime factors of 10 are [2, 5] -> neededPrimes = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7]

x = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 = 2520
```

Here's a code, and I hope it's clear:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The number to find its smallest multiple
    var n = 20;
    // A list that contains all primes that are founded across the calculation
    var calculatedPrimes = new List<int>();
    // Start through the numbers that x (the output number) should be divisible by
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // Get primes of i
        var primes = GetPrimeFactors(i);
        // Loop through primes of i and add to "calculatedPrimes" the ones that are not 
        // in "calculatedPrimes"
        primes.ForEach(prime =>
        {
            if (!calculatedPrimes.Contains(prime) ||
                calculatedPrimes.Count(p => p == prime) < primes.Count(p => p == prime))
            {
                calculatedPrimes.Add(prime);
            }
        });
    }

    // The output number should be the multiple of all primes in "calculatedPrimes" list
    var x = calculatedPrimes.Aggregate(1, (res, p) => res * p);
    Console.WriteLine(x);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

// A function to get prime factors of a given number n
// (example: if n = 12 then this will return [2, 2, 3])
private static List<int> GetPrimeFactors(int n)
{
    var res = new List<int>();
    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        res.Add(2);
        n /= 2;
    }

    for (var i = 3; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i += 2)
    { 
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            res.Add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 2)
        res.Add(n);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the OP's question. He's not asking how to solve the problem, but rather why his LINQ solution uses so much memory.

Comment: The main problem is with allocated memory and performance, and this solves the problem. You can also note that OP wanted to accept a code written in comments if it's posted as an answer, and that comment doesn't contain any information about why OP's LINQ solution uses so much memory.

Comment: None of which invalidates my comment: your answer doesn't answer the OP's question. He asked two questions: 1) Why did his LINQ query run out of memory? 2) Is there a LINQ query that can solve the problem?

Comment: thx for summing it up, and for haim770 for providing a much cleaner solution, I was too deep into groups to realize I don't need them at all. I still wonder if MS missed an opportunity here. Enumerable.Range could return an IOrderedEnumerable and a GroupBy could work more memory friendly with that, or so I think.